# What should I do to use a .as3proj file in Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashdevelop

thing is, I have to do some modifications at my work, but I never used Flashdevelop, only Flash Builder.

However, the project I need to modify was made with Flashdevelop, it comes with a .as3file, no fla file anywhere.

So, what do I need to do in order to use this project in Flash Builder?, just creating a new project and browsing the path file with the src .as files is enough?, or do I need to do something else?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not expect you'd be able to reuse a FlashDevelop project within Flash Builder.  However, there is no reason you can't use the same ActionScript files that youw rote in FlashDevelop in a Flash Builder project.  There are plenty of ways you may try to do this.  I'd start by creating a Flash Builder project.  Then you can:

1. Copy the code from your
   FlashDevelop project into your Flash
   Builder project's source directory
2. Create a mapped source directory
   in Flash Builder that points to the
   source of your FlashDevelop project.
3. Encapsulate your common code into a
   Flash Builder Library Project and
   create a SWC which can then be used
   in the Flash Builder project and the
   FlashDevelop project.  [Note: I
   assume FlashDevelop also provides a
   way to create SWCs].

I'll also note that fla is the file format for Flash Professional; and is not supported by Flash Builder--so far as I know.

Comment: Seems kind of complicated, what do you mean by "common code", and, that encapsulation I need to do it using flashdevelop right?

Comment: Which one seems complicated; I suggested three options and consider the first two trivial to implement.  Common code is any code you want to share between the two projects.  It sounds like this situation may be "All of it" in which case you can move everything except the main application file into a library.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didnt see that those were 3 different options, I thought they were steps or something, my bad, its early in the morning I need a coffy :p

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a new Flash builder project and drop your code in the src folder and take it from there.

That is the simplest option and what I would do. These are two different development environments and you don't really want to import the code from your flashdevelop project folder: instead duplicate that folder in a new location and as I just said above create a new project there.

And of course, ask yourself if you need to work with two different programs. I used to use Flashdevelop for many years but now I use Flashbuilder only. Go with one and you will find things easier.

Thomas